# Flash can't contact my RESTful webservice when hosted online

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, httpresponse

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with a Flash project I'm working on. It's a web game that contacts a RESTful webservice to save and load gamedata, that seems to break when hosted online but works OK when I use it locally.

When I run the project offline (in the Flash IDE), everything works: I get a HTTP response code of 200/500 (depending on if it's a new user or not), which is 100% expected behaviour. All data uploads and downloads successfully.

However: when I host the project online, my queries immediately return a response code of zero, which breaks the project.

I know, based on other threads, that Flash's HTTP response handling is pretty bad, and actually I'm not *too* bothered about the response as I don't do anything with it apart from use it to check things are working.

I'm assuming this is a security sandbox issue, or similar, but I'm completely out of ideas. I've made sure the Flash files are set to networked ones (in my Publish settings), and have allowed script access in the HTML that holds the file. I've also screwed around with Security.allowDomain("*") and nothing seems to work.

Can anyone suggest what I may be missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it all hosted on the same domain, and using the same protocol?

Comment: They're on different domains. Would I need crossdomain.xml for something like this?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to put a crossdomain.xml on the domain that holds your service.

Comment: OK, I've added a totally open crossdomain.xml and am still getting a response of zero. Does this look right? :

<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain- policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/> 
   <allow-access-from domain="*"/> 
 </cross-domain-policy>

Comment: Where did you put that crossdomain.xml?

Comment: The webservice is located at mywebservice.domain.co.uk. I've tried placing it at mywebservice.domain.co.uk/crossdomain.xml, and also domain.co.uk/crossdomain.xml, and in both cases it doesn't give me anything different. Hmm.

Comment: Are you using the same protocol for loading the SWF and making requests to the service? If one is HTTP and the other HTTPS then you will need to change your crossdomain.xml.

Comment: The webservice is just a HTTP address, and in the Flash I'm just using a standard URLLoader, there's no security or anything implemented. The game SWF that contains the webservice calls is also loaded into a holder swf, would this make a difference?

Comment: I've got a debug panel that reports all status events and errors that runs over the top of my projects, would your solution add additional data? I'm currently getting HTTPstatus codes, security event issues and IOerrors

edit - sorry, I'm not 'getting' errors, but they get reported if they crop up (for example if I put in a random URL I get the correct error)

Comment: OK, solution found. Turns out the external webservice we were trying to contact doesn't work on our internal network here (we've been using a dev address to test). Even though I hosted it on an external site, it was still going through the internal network and erroring out. I tried it on a tablet using 3G, and presto: worked like a charm. Thanks for the help folks! Tried to mark this as answered but I'm too new!!